# php регулярное выражение

Tags: php

Как найти и заменить в строке все подстроки после ( **=** ) конец подстроки перед переносом строки ( **\r или \n** )
Хочу менять переменные в файле(пример):

```
lang=en,ru

password=6fbde3e2135f10ee603ff6f59bc97d4b0a4d4e9a

session=

pass_complexity=500000

pass_complexity_js=15000
```

Comment: а подробнее можно? че-то я ничего не понял. Желательно с примерами

Comment: @BOPOH ,  Хочу менять переменные в файле

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. Добавьте набор примеров. Как сейчас → как надо

Comment: ну так что-то вроде `/=(.+)$/` и менять на что надо

Comment: @Grundy , а как определить переменную к которой менять значение?

Comment: не понял вопроса :)

Comment: `/([^=]+)=(.+)$/` - первое совпадение - имя

Comment: так вы если меняете определенные переменные, то эти переменные в регулярку и добавляйте

Comment: @splash58, а `}` что делает?

Comment: описался - поменяйте на обычную скобку

Comment: @splash58, редактирование комментария доступно первый 5 минут, у вас еще есть время самому исправить :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// для чтения данных
$file = file('yourfile.txt');
$arrConf = array();

foreach($file as $_file) {
   if(trim($_file)!="") {
      $tmp = explode('=',$_file);
      $arrConf[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
   }
}

// можем поменять сдесь 
$arrConf['lang'] = 'fr,ru';

// и записать обратно
$resultCompile = '';
foreach($arrConf as $_key => $_val) {
   $resultCompile = "$_key=$_val\n"; 
}

file_put_contents('yourfile.txt',$resultCompile);
```

С использованием регулярок есть два момента:

- Нагрузка на процессор
- Велика вероятность ошибки патерна, в конце концов конец строки \n\r и т.д.

Плюсы такого подхода у нас есть конкретная переменая, по которой мы можем обратиться и перезаписать её.

п.с. Укажите расширение файла? в php есть расширение для работы с ini http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php

если оно прокатит для парсинга выше то можно привести алгоритм в следующий вид

```
// для чтения данных
$arrConf = parse_ini_file('yourfile.ini');

// можем поменять сдесь 
$arrConf['lang'] = 'fr,ru';

// и записать обратно
$resultCompile = '';
foreach($arrConf as $_key => $_val) {
   $resultCompile = "$_key=$_val\n"; 
}

file_put_contents('yourfile.ini',$resultCompile);
```